# Looping Through Files to Run PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to loop through an unknown number of Excel files in a folder and rename the 1st worksheet in each file to a specific name.

What I have so far is:

```
Clear-Host
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PowerShell\BA" -Name -Include *.xlsx
Write-Output $file
```

This does list out all of the Excel files in the folder.  I am then trying to run one of the commands from the ImportExcel module to rename the first worksheet to "Sheet1".

```
foreach ($i in $file )
{
$xl= Open-ExcelPackage $file
$sheet1 = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[1]
$sheet1.Name ="Sheet1"
Close-ExcelPackage $xl
}
```

But when I run this code, I get the following error for each of the files in the folder:

```
WARNING: Could not find C:\WINDOWS\system32\11.25.2020_JH_BDX.xlsx 11.25.2020_JH_COV.xlsx 11.25.2020_JH_MISC.xlsx bx_1_coverage_report_2020-11-25 Final V.1 .xlsx bx_2_misc_report_2020-11-25 Final V.1 .xlsx bx_3_bordereau_report_2020-11-25 Final. V.1 .xlsx ic
at_cov_20201126053019.xlsx icat_misc_20201126053024.xlsx
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:8 char:1
+ $sheet1 = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[1]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
 
Close-ExcelPackage : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ExcelPackage' because it is null.
At line:10 char:20
+ Close-ExcelPackage $xl
+                    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Close-ExcelPackage], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Close-ExcelPackage
```

If I run in 32-bit instead of 64-bit, it looks like it is looking for the files here:

```
WARNING: Could not find C:\Users\1192643\11.25.2020_JH_BDX.xlsx 11.25.2020_JH_COV.xlsx 11.25.2020_JH_MISC.xlsx bx_1_coverage_report_2020-11-25 Final V.1 .xlsx bx_2_misc_report_2020-11-25 Final V.1 .xlsx bx_3_bordereau_report_2020-11-25 Final. V.1 .xlsx icat_
cov_20201126053019.xlsx icat_misc_20201126053024.xlsx
```

I'm not sure why it is looking in `C:\WINDOWS\system32` or my User director for the Excel files.  I have tried to ensure it looks in the correct folder by adding the full path in the `foreach` block with the following:

```
foreach ($i in $file )
{
$xl= Open-ExcelPackage "C:\PowerShell\BA\"$file
$sheet1 = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[1]
$sheet1.Name ="Sheet1"
Close-ExcelPackage $xl
}
```

But that does not work either.  Could anyone help me understand what I am missing here? I am on version 5.1.17763.1490.

Updating the `$xl` variable to `$xl= Open-ExcelPackage $i.fullname` gives the following errors - so it seems to have the right path now, but it doesn't like the code.
Open-ExcelPackage : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\PowerShell\BA\RenameWorksheet.ps1:23 char:24
+ $xl= Open-ExcelPackage $i.fullname
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Open-ExcelPackage], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Open-ExcelPackage

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\PowerShell\BA\RenameWorksheet.ps1:24 char:1
+ $sheet1 = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[1]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
 
The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At C:\PowerShell\BA\RenameWorksheet.ps1:25 char:1
+ $sheet1.Name ="Sheet1"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
 
Close-ExcelPackage : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ExcelPackage' because it is null.
At C:\PowerShell\BA\RenameWorksheet.ps1:26 char:20
+ Close-ExcelPackage $xl
+                    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Close-ExcelPackage], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Close-ExcelPackage
```

To test the code, I was able to update the worksheet name in a specific .xlsx file by using:

```
$xl= Open-ExcelPackage "C:\PowerShell\BA\11.25.2020_JH_MISC.xlsx"
$sheet1 = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[1]
$sheet1.Name ="Sheet1"
Close-ExcelPackage $xl
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try changing your `$xl` to `$xl= Open-ExcelPackage $i.fullname`

Comment: The name parameter on get-childitem just returns the file name. Change that to -filter. Then you may need to use $file.fullname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reference $file inside the loop.  If you are looking for a handle on one of the files, use $i, because that's the name you chose in the setup of your foreach.  Note that I have put the $i inside the quoted string.

```
foreach ($i in $file )
{
$xl= Open-ExcelPackage "C:\PowerShell\BA\$i"
$sheet1 = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[1]
$sheet1.Name ="Sheet1"
Close-ExcelPackage $xl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with PowerShell, there are two things to remember.

1. PowerShell is object-oriented.
2. PowerShell uses pipelines.

Here we have a variable and a loop. Both can be eliminated by switching to a pipeline.

Take care to read the help file for [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1).

As Doug mentioned, the `-Name` parameter:

> -Name
>
> Gets only the names of the items in the location. The output is a string object that can be sent down the pipeline to other commands. Wildcards are permitted.

Here we go from a `FileInfo` object to a `String`. So we lose valuable information like the location of each file: `$_.FullName` This contributed to the issue with `$i.fullname`

Also, `-Include` requires a special wildcard in the `-Path`.

> -Include
>
> Specifies, as a string array, an item or items that this cmdlet includes in the operation. The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as "*.txt". Wildcard characters are permitted. The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the contents of an item, such as **C:\Windows\***, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory.

`Get-ChildItem` won't produce any output unless you follow this pattern or (for some reason) include the `-Name` parameter. This might be why you started using the `-Name` parameter in the first place.

### Final Answer

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PowerShell\BA\*" -Include "*.xlsx" | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    $xl = Open-ExcelPackage $_.FullName
    $sheet1 = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[1]
    $sheet1.Name ="Sheet1"
    Close-ExcelPackage $xl
  }
```

---

If you have a large number of files and are able to install PowerShell 7, it might be possible to use the `-Parallel` parameter to speed up processing.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\PowerShell\BA\*" -Include "*.xlsx" | 
  ForEach-Object -Parallel { 
    $xl = Open-ExcelPackage $_.FullName
    $sheet1 = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[1]
    $sheet1.Name ="Sheet1"
    Close-ExcelPackage $xl
  } -ThrottleLimit 5
```

If you're *not* a local admin, it is possible to get PowerShell 7 from the Store.

- [Get PowerShell - Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9MZ1SNWT0N5D)
- [ForEach-Object (Microsoft.PowerShell.Core) - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1)
- [What's New in PowerShell 7.0 - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7.1)

### Interpreting Error Messages

Either `C:\WINDOWS\system32\` or `$env:USERPROFILE` is the default working directory when PowerShell is loaded.

Looking at our path:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\11.25.2020_JH_BDX.xlsx
```

We have one default directory and one custom file.

This is an indication that we're only providing the file name to our function. E.g. `$_.Name`

In our case, the root cause of this error is `Get-ChildItem -Name` which produces only file names as strings. It would be necessary to qualify those file names per Walter. Or to remove `-Name` and use the `FullName` property of [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-5.0#properties) per Doug / Itchydon.

---

> Open-ExcelPackage : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. 
> $xl= Open-ExcelPackage $i.fullname

Here there are two clues.

One, we just changed

```
$xl= Open-ExcelPackage $file
```

to

```
$xl= Open-ExcelPackage $i.fullname
```

So, `$i.fullname` must be the issue.

Two, we can trace the logic of the error message backward.

`it is null` -> `parameter 'Path'` -> `Open-ExcelPackage Cannot bind` -> `Open-ExcelPackage $i.fullname`

The two most likely possibilities are that `$i` or `$i.FullName` never existed in the first place.

If we check, we see that `$i` has no `FullName` property.

#### Debugging

Set a breakpoint for the `$xl= Open-ExcelPackage $i.fullname` line in your script file.

For example,

```
1  # C:\users\michael\desktop\vim\demo 1.ps1
2  $file = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\users\michael\desktop\vim" -Name -Include *.out
3  
4  
5  foreach ($i in $file )
6  {
7  $xl= Open-ExcelPackage $i.fullname
8  $sheet1 = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[1]
9  $sheet1.Name ="Sheet1"
10 Close-ExcelPackage $xl
11 }
```

```
> # from the shell
> Set-PSBreakpoint -Script '.\demo 1.ps1' -Line 7

  ID Script            Line Command           Variable         Action
  -- ------            ---- -------           --------         ------
   0 demo 1.ps1           7

> & '.\demo 1.ps1'
Entering debug mode. Use h or ? for help.

Hit Line breakpoint on 'C:\Users\Michael\desktop\vim\demo 1.ps1:7'

At C:\Users\Michael\desktop\vim\demo 1.ps1:7 char:1
+ $xl= Open-ExcelPackage $i.fullname
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> $i | gm

   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ...
CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), i...
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)
...

> # We have a string. 

> $i | Get-Member | Where-Object { $_.name -match "^f" }
> # No match for properties starting with the letter 'f'. 
> # So, strings don't have a 'FullName' property. 
> q # to quit the debugger
```

---

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' ... 
> Cannot index into a null array. 
> The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object... 
> Close-ExcelPackage : Cannot bind argument ...

Oftentimes resolving the first error will either fix the code or make the larger issue apparent.

For example, we know that `$sheet1 = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets[1]` (which depends on $xl being defined) won't work if `$xl= Open-ExcelPackage $i.fullname` didn't work.

There isn't much point in looking at the second, third, fourth, etc errors until the first one is resolved.

### Pipelines

The two things to understand about [pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.1) are that:

1. Cmdlets are connected with pipes `|` (ASCII 124) and
2. An [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#_) is used to represent the current object being processed: `$_`

This gives us the basic tools to connect cmdlets `cmdlet | cmdlet` and to refer to the properties of the current object being processed `ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }`